# Utility that will write a large file local or via UNC, read it back for errors

Tags: networking, corruption

A long time ago, I worked for a company that had a neat in-house utility that did something very simple. It's allowed you to write a file at a size you specify. It would then read that file back and check it for errors. You could write the file to a local disk, a mapped network share, or a UNC path (presuming you had permissions, of course).

Using this utility, I was able to narrow down the source of very intermittent file corruption one day. (Turned out an on-board DRAM module in a RAID produced an occasional memory error.)

I would really, really like to get some utility that performs this same function. I am not asking for the utility this company produced, but rather something that does a similar function.

Edit: I prefer a Windows utility. CLI is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrm. Without some obviously bad ram to test, I'm wondering if this might work...

```
 # will create a 10MB file. Adjust as necessary
 dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/file bs=1M count=10 

 cp /path/to/file /path/to/other/file

 md5sum /path/to/file /path/to/other/file
```

At this point, both files should have the same md5sum.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I should have specified I hope to do it in Winders. :-(

Comment: You could get dd for windows via cygwin http://www.cygwin.org/

Comment: I will do that if I can't find a Win32 option. I'd have to install this on a production server to do some testing so I want to minimize changes to the environment as much as possible, if that makes sense.

Comment: @tcv MSYS will give you enough of a shell to do this with: http://mingw.org/wiki/MSYS - I'd also suggest reading from `/dev/urandom` so that you're not just testing "copy zero, ten million times", which may work when real files fail.

Comment: When you say "reading from /dev/urandom," do you mean to create a file from /dev/urandom? Such as dd if=/dev/urandom of=/path/to/sexy/randomized/file bs=1M count=10 ??

Comment: @tcv Exactly that.